# gevent monkey patch breaks gevent.sleep(0)?

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent

I'm asking this question after a full day of hacking and trying to figure out what's wrong here.
I want to send a request using the `requests` package, and do it in a non-blocking mode.
For that, I'm using the fine `gevent` package with its monkey patching abilities, which I have been using for a long time.

I have a main loop that receives a message and spawns a new greenlet that creates a POST request for every message. Following the `spawn` command, the main loop does a `gevent.sleep(0)` to allow the greenlets to do their work.

The code below is a simplified example (without the main loop):

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import gevent    # (version 1.0.2)
import requests  # version 2.7.0

def f():
    requests.post('http://localhost:8888/', data='*' * 80)

gevent.spawn(f)
gevent.sleep(0)
```

If you try to run if from the command line (or a file), **the request will NOT be sent**.
After playing around, I managed to get this code to send the request if I:

1. Remove the monkey patching line (which is not good because then it will be blocking), **or**
2. change the value of the `sleep` to **0.1** (which is not good because I really don't want the main loop to sleep).

Both options are a big NO for me.
Any chance someone knows why this strange behaviour and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out it's the desired behaviour.
Here's a link to more details on this subject: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/744

Answer (score 0):

So, I think what you need is: `gevent.joinall([g1, g2, ...])`, but not `gevent.sleep`

Comment: `joinall` does work, but my use case is more complex than the example I posted above, which is a simplified scenario of my real world situation.